# Figures output in Jupyter

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The attached minimal example implements multithreading, to plot several simple figures.

For the attached example, there is no output at all. In case that the first line in scheme_fun_2 `#     print('.')` is uncommented and replaced by `print('.')`, the figures appear as expected.

The question: How I can show the figures without the useless printing of dots?

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from matplotlib.pyplot import title, plot, show
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

def scheme_fun_2(num):
#     print('.')
    plot(np.arange(10)**2)
    title(num)
    show()

pool = mp.Pool(processes=7)
tmp = [pool.apply_async(scheme_fun_2, args=(num,)) for num in range(3)]
output = [p.get() for p in tmp]
```

Comment: The behavior when you uncomment `print` is unexpected. All the plot commands  should go to the same axes but three separate axes are created instead for no apparent reason. I am afraid you are invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not sure that I understood you correctly, does it means that I have to modify the code and it is written not correctly or there is a bug in the Jupyter?